# Check string matches exact format swift 5

Tags: swift, regex, string

I want to check if a string matches an exact regex pattern;

Currently, even though the string being compared is not an exact match, my function is returning true.

Pattern String: `"([0-9],[0-9])"`

For example,

(1,1) is **valid**

(5,4) is **valid**

Only strings entered in this format are valid I.E. Bracket Number Comma Number Bracket (Without spaces)

I.E.

[5,5] is **not valid**

{5,5] is **not valid**.

5,5 is **not valid**

Code I am using to check:

```
let stringToCheck = "[5,5]"

return stringToCheck.range(of: "([0-9],[0-9])", options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
```

Can anyone help me with how to adjust this to check for exact matches in line with my pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks to be working good @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things:

- Escape parentheses
- Add anchors because in the current code, the regex can match a part of a string.

You can thus use

```swift
stringToCheck.range(of: #"^\([0-9],[0-9]\)\z"#, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
```

Note the `#` chars on both ends, they allow escaping with single backslashes.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[0-9]` - a single ASCII digit (add `+` after `]` to match one or more digits)
- `,` - a comma
- `[0-9]` - a single ASCII digit (add `+` after `]` to match one or more digits)
- `\)` - a `)` char
- `\z` - the very end of string (if linebreaks cannot be present in the string, `$` is enough).